# Writing loop values within a function into Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, function, loops

The function below is part of googlesheets quickstart.py to allow people to read a Googlesheet URL.
I am able to run the test and getting the print to work.
See the print statement in the function below:
print('%s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s' % (row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3], row[4], row[5],row[6],row[7]))
My ultimate goal is to capture the data in the print into a pandas dataframe instead.  All my attempts did not work.

```
def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.
    Prints values from a sample spreadsheet.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Sheets API
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        #print('Name, Major:')

        for row in values:
#             d = {'Case_Type':row.Case_Type,
#              'Date':row.Date,
#              'Cases':row.Cases,
#              'Country_Region':row.Country_Region,
#              'Lat':Lat,
#              'Long':Long}
#             L.append(d)
# df = pd.DataFrame(L)


           #Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 7.
          print('%s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s' % (row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3], row[4], row[5],row[6],row[7]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **values** seems to be a 2D list, try doing

```py
pd.DataFrame.from_records(values, columns=['Date', 'Cases', 'Country_Region', 'Lat', 'Long'])
```

Comment: Thank you for replying and making the suggestion.  I added it, and it's taking forever to run. No errors are generated.  To give you an idea, the print statement takes about 2min. After that,        
        for row in values:

            df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(values, columns=['Case_Type','Cases','Difference','Date','Country_Region','Province_State','Admin2',  'Combined_Key','FIPS','Lat', 'Long','Prep_Flow_Runtime','Table_Names']
Just runs forever.until hangs.

Comment: Did you put the code pd.DataFrame.from_records(values, columns=['Date', 'Cases', 'Country_Region', 'Lat', 'Long']) inside of the loop? Since it only needs to be run once, it does not need to be in that for loop

Comment: Hello, I have tried it outside of the loop initially, right after the line values = result.get('values', []).  It produces a blank df.  Thanks.